# linq query with list

Tags: linq, list, selection, where-clause

i have a simple query. Method-1 works well. But i don't understand what is wrong with method-2?

//method-1

```
        List<string> li = new List<string>();
        List<string> liSNB = new List<string>();
        li.Add("result1");
        li.Add("result2");
        li.Add("result3");
        var vQuery = from ssoli in li.AsEnumerable()
                     where li.Contains(ssoli)
                     where ssoli.Contains("2")
                     select new
                     {
                         soName = ssoli,
                     };

        liSNB.Clear();
        foreach (var v in vQuery)
            liSNB.Add(v.soName);
        li.Clear();
        li.AddRange(liSNB);
        lbxLinq.Items.AddRange(li.ToArray());//add results2
```

//method-2

```
        List<string> liSNB = new List<string>();
        liSNB.Add("result1");
        liSNB.Add("result2");
        liSNB.Add("result3");
        var vQuery = from ssoli in liSNB.AsEnumerable()
                     where liSNB.Contains(ssoli)
                     where ssoli.Contains("2")
                     select new
                     {
                         soName = ssoli,
                     };

        liSNB.Clear();
        foreach (var v in vQuery)
            liSNB.Add(v.soName);
        lbxLinq.Items.AddRange(liSNB.ToArray());//add nothing WHY???
```

Why no results in method-2 why? I have been workind for 2 days on just this situation. Is it bug or something? Thank you for answers initially.

Comment: Have you heard of LINQ's deferred execution? `liSNB.Clear();` clears the list which also will "clear" the not executed query. You could persist it via `ToList`.

Comment: no i have'nt heard yet. is it about this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq query executes when the result is accessed, so you need to call `ToArray()` or `ToList()` after query:

```
var vQuery = (from ssoli in liSNB.AsEnumerable()
              where liSNB.Contains(ssoli) // this line is pointless because you are checking in same list
              where ssoli.Contains("2")
              select new
              {
                soName = ssoli,
              }).ToList();
```

Now your query will get executed when `ToList()` is called and result will be in `vQuery`.

The line `where liSNB.Contains(ssoli)` is not needed because you checking the source list item in the source list, so all items will be filtered, means no filtering will apply.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `where liSNB.Contains(ssoli)` is pointless since it's checking for every string in the list, if it's in the list.

Comment: As is the `AsEnumerable`. As is selecting things from a list, building a list of the results, clearing the original list, copying everything from the results list to the original list, and then copying everything from the original list to a final list. `Add ToList to the end of the query` is very rarely a satisfactory answer.

Comment: in a fact i use a lot of queries like that so where liSNB.Contains(ssoli) is necessary for me. You are pretty right for this code but i' ve shorten my code for this question. Ehsan' s answers is working now for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since the linq uses deferred execution,your query is actualy executing in here:

```
foreach (var v in vQuery)
```

In your second code snippet you are removing all the items from `liSNB` before executing the query.So it doesn't return anything.

Btw this doesn't make any little sense, you can remove it:

```
where liSNB.Contains(ssoli)
```

You can read more about deferred execution in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'll run over some mistakes in your second code block; most of them apply to the first block too.

```
    List<string> liSNB = new List<string>();
    liSNB.Add("result1");
    liSNB.Add("result2");
    liSNB.Add("result3");
```

The `AsEnumerable` in this line achieves nothing:

```
    var vQuery = from ssoli in liSNB.AsEnumerable()
```

This `Contains` check achieves nothing - of course `ssoli` is in the list or it wouldn't show up in the query:

```
                 where liSNB.Contains(ssoli)
```

This is fine:

```
                 where ssoli.Contains("2")
```

There's no reason to nest the string you want here - just `select ssoli` would work:

```
                 select new
                 {
                     soName = ssoli,
                 };
```

The query has not run yet - it is deferred. By clearing the list here, you have nothing to query over:

```
    liSNB.Clear();
```

While you are in the `foreach` loop the query is "running". By altering the source list while the query is running, you will cause the query to throw an exception. (You'd also need to remove `soName.` here if you stopped selecting it above):

```
    foreach (var v in vQuery)
        liSNB.Add(v.soName);
```

(Actually in your example you only have one matching item so you get away with it. If you had two or more items matching the query you'd be in trouble).

<del>The `ToArray` is pointless here:</del> *I stand corrected, the method takes an `object[]`.*

```
    lbxLinq.Items.AddRange(liSNB.ToArray());
```

Comment: thank you for your helps but lbxLinq.Items.AddRange(liSNB.ToArray()); is necessary because lbxLinq is a ListBox